# Django rest-framework creating a view without model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new to Django rest-framework and trying to render a simple JSON view not based on the model. I could not figure out how to do this since all of the examples involves rendering JSON from the Model classes. Below is the simple example what I was trying to do.

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()

def comment_view(request):
    comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')
    serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
    json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
    return json
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use it like [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view()
def comment_view(request):
    comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')
    serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Finally don't forget to put it in the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('comments/', comment_view, name='comment-view'),
]
```